# Get value in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby, I have

```
res = [[0, :product, "client"], [0, :os, "windows"], [0, :architecture, "32rs"]]
```

I want to get value of os. I can do it by res[1][2], but I don't want to rely on the index as it can change. What I have is the key i.e. :os, so what is the best way to find it?

Comment: If you don't want to rely on array indices then this data should really be structured in a hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the way the data is structured, you could do something like this:

```
res.select{|h| h.include?(:os)}.map(&:last)
```

But it seems to me that your data is better represented with a hash.

```
res_hash = res.each_with_object({}) do |value, memo| 
  memo[value[1]] = value[2]
end
# => {:product=>"client", :os=>"windows", :architecture=>"32rs"}
```

Then you can access discrete data properties like this:

```
res_hash[:os]
# => "windows"
```

Comment: You can use Hash[] instead of inject to build a hash.

Comment: Thanks. I did not initially wanted to change it. But later I decided to convert it to hash after reading yours and @Boris comment below. By the way what about if I have nested array e.g. res = [[0, :product, "client"], [0, :os, "windows"], [0, :architecture, "32rs"], [0, :address, [0, :link, "XwjmnS"]] and now I want to get the value of link?

Answer (score 4):

```
hash = Hash[res.map{ |a| a[1..-1] }]
hash[:os] # windows
```

Comment: +1, though those padding space on `[ ]` severely hurt my eyes

Answer (score 0):

While @pje answered under the assumption that you cannot change the data, I will elaborate a bit on his suggestion to structure the data in a hash:

```
res = [ [0, product: "client"],
        [0, os: "windows"],
        [0, architecture: "32rs"] ]
```

Minor change in comma presence and colon position causes Ruby compiler to parse [] expression as having a hash for its last element:

```
[ [0, {product: "client}], [0, {os: "windows"}], [0, architecture: "32rs"] ]
```

Then you can address what you need comfortably as

```
res[1][1][:os]
```

If you are concerned that the order of the second level arrays would change, you should restructure the data even deeper, such as:

```
res = { product: [ 0, "client" ], os: [ 0, "windows" ], architecture: [ 0, "32rs" ] ]
```

And address it that way.

Comment: Thanks Boris, never knew that changes of colon and comma can make that difference. Happy to learn something new today :)

Comment: That one is quite poorly documented.